# Manifest in maven-shade-plugin is not working

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

## Goal: Create build number and put it in the manifest generated by maven-shade-plugin. Then, read that build number.

I have used `ManifestResourceTransformer` and declared manifestEntries there.

```
<!-- Maven Shade Plugin -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <executions>
     <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass>app.MainApp</mainClass>
              <manifestEntries>
                <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
              </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
          <filters>
            <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Build number is correctly generated from the resulting log of `mvn package`.

Then, I read the generated manifest:

```
    Manifest mf = new Manifest();
    mf.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF"));
    Attributes attr = mf.getMainAttributes();

    System.out.println("Manifest-Version : " + attr.getValue("Manifest-Version"));
    System.out.println("Created by : " + attr.getValue("Created-By"));
    System.out.println("Built by : " + attr.getValue("Built-By"));
    System.out.println("Implementation-Build: " + mf.getEntries().get("Implementation-Build"));
```

### Result

```
Manifest-Version : 1.0
Created by : 1.6.0_65-b14-466-11M4802 (Apple Inc.)
Built by : null
Implementation-Build: null
```

For good measure, I even hardcoded the build number.

```
<manifestEntries>
  <Implementation-Build>123123</Implementation-Build>
</manifestEntries>
```

The result still the same.

### Thoughts: The manifest really looks like the DEFAULT manifest instead of anything.

## Edit: My pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyGroupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyArtifactId</artifactId>
  <name>MyApp</name>

  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/myorg/myrepo.git</connection>

  <developerConnection>scm:git:https://github.com/myorg/myrepo.git</developerConnection>
<tag>DEVELOP</tag>
  <url>https://github.com/myorg/myrepo.git</url>
</scm>

<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src</directory>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
  <resource>
    <directory>resources</directory>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
</resources>
<plugins>
  <!-- Maven Shade Plugin -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <executions>
     <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
          <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass>app.MainApp</mainClass>
              <manifestEntries>
                <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
              </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
          <filters>
            <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </filter>
          </filters>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>create</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <format>{0,date,yyyyMMddHHmmss}</format>
      <items>
        <item>timestamp</item>
      </items>
      <doCheck>true</doCheck>
      <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <!-- Deploy the web site -->
    <groupId>com.github.github</groupId>
    <artifactId>site-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.9</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>site</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>site-deploy</phase>
        <configuration>
            <!-- must match the server's id  -->
            <server>github</server>
            <!-- The commit message -->
            <message>Building site for my project</message>
            <!-- The location where the site is uploaded -->
            <path>${site.path}</path>
            <!-- Use merge or override the content -->
            <merge>true</merge>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>4thline-repo</id>
    <url>http://4thline.org/m2</url>
    <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
<repository>
  <id>clojars.org</id>
  <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
</repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
  </dependency>
  ...
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: The pom file is not complete and missing important things...Apart from that why have you changed the default folder locations? What kind of packaging do you have?

Comment: Missing important things such as? I intentionally didn't include things such as <modelVersion>, <groupId>, <artifactId>... apart from these, there's a myriad of dependencies. Not sure if these are helpful and related. Anyway, I'll edit to include a more complete pom.

Comment: I'm new to Maven. Not sure to your question of why I change the default folder location. Packaging, it's jar. And I used maven-shade-plugin to create one big uber jar.

Answer (score 0):

how do you run the attached code? If you are running it as a test, it will produce your output because the test classpath does not include the MANIFEST.MF file. You will need to include the generated (+shaded) jar in your classpath for that code to run.